# Using objects/calling methods inside event response

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Let's say I have in an ionic app a class like

```
export class DetailPage {
    ...

  constructor(
    ...
    public popoverCtrl: PopoverController
  ) {
    ...
  }

  mouseDown(ev) {

    let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(PopoverPiece ..... )

  }
```

with a method ionViewDidLoad as follows:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    ...
    object1.addEventListener("mousedown", this.mouseDown, false);
}
```

Ok. I CAN'T create the popover because when mouseDown is fired, I am not (let me say, probably not so accurate) in an instance 
of DetailPage and this.popoverCtrl is undefined.

How can I do something similar?! How can I create, for example, a popover to respond to a mousedown?
I cannot create inside mouseDown() an instance of DetailPage beacuse the constructor has a lot of arguments I don't say how to create.

Can I create an object 'popoverCtrl' inside the  mouseDown() function?! And how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scope is changing when you pass the function `this.mouseDown` into the event listener. Use arrow function or `bind`.

```
object1.addEventListener("mousedown", this.mouseDown.bind(this), false);
```